# Paypal How to override payment definition?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I've created some billing plans and now I want to override the payment definitions when creating the billing agreement. Is that possible?

I know that I can override the merchant preferences and the charge models but I haven't found anything to override the payment definitions.

The use case would be a user that subscribes a service (billing plan) but with a discount associated.

I'm using the REST API.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and looking for the solution, too. Did you find any?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

- Create a billing agreement with override_merchant_preferences. (initial amount)
- After creating the billing agreement - get agreement_id
- Update the billing agreement with patch_request (recurring amount)

***Update on April 2019:***

On April 2019, PayPal added new Subscriptions API.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

New API supports revising current subscriptions.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#revise-subscription